# Angular pagination doesn't work - datas sent from backend

Tags: angular, angular-material, pagination, paginator

I used the table with paginator here https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview. I pulled data from backend

dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<List_Product>;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<List_Product>(allProducts.products);
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

I also made the connections. I can list the products, but when I list 5 products, I cannot move to the next page. Is this part not working? I couldn't figure out why?

My codes: list.component.ts

```
export class ListComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {

  constructor(spiner: NgxSpinnerService, private productService: ProductService, private alertifyService: AlertifyService) {
    super(spiner)
  }

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'stock', 'price', 'createdDate', 'updatedDate'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<List_Product>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  async getProducts() {
    this.showSpinner(SpinnerType.SquareLoader);
    const allProducts: { totalProductCount: number; products: List_Product[] } = await this.productService.read(this.paginator ? this.paginator.pageIndex : 0, this.paginator ? this.paginator.pageSize : 5, () => this.hideSpinner(SpinnerType.BallSpinFadeRotating), errorMessage => this.alertifyService.message(errorMessage, {
      dismissOthers: true,
      messageType: MessageType.Error,
      position: Position.TopRight
    }))
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<List_Product>(allProducts.products);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    console.log("paginator: " + this.dataSource.paginator.pageSize)
  }

  async pageChanged() {
    await this.getProducts();
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.getProducts();
  }
}
```

list.component.html:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="stock">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Stock </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.stock}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Price </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.price}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="createdDate">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Created Date </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.createdDate}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="updatedDate">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Updated Date </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.updatedDate}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator (page)="pageChanged()"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                 showFirstLastButtons
                 aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

product.service.ts :

```
async read(page: number = 0, size: number = 5, successCallBack?: () => void, errorCallBack?: (errorMessage: string) => void): Promise<{ totalProductCount: number; products: List_Product[] }> {
    const promiseData: Promise<{ totalProductCount: number; products: List_Product[] }> =  firstValueFrom(this.HttpClientService.get<{ totalProductCount: number; products: List_Product[] }>({
      controller: "products",
      queryString: `page=${page}&size=${size}`
    }));

    promiseData.then(d => successCallBack())
      .catch((errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => errorCallBack(errorResponse.message))

    return await promiseData;
  }
```

Comment: can you put this on a stackblitz so I can see a live demo?

Comment: I solved it, but if you want to see I can put on  stackblitz ?

Comment: sure.  I figured it was the paginator length as I looked at my angular project and cross checked to see what I had that you did not. Yes I would want to see on stackblitz. Your solution is rather interesting as I would have just added "[length]="1000" to the mat-paginator. but instead you chose to create a variable and store the value of that variable and assign to the paginator length

Comment: Ok, here is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-lrv42k?file=README.md
and path is src/app/admin/product/list

Comment: Your served app looks like this https://prnt.sc/1ZyBTNs912zw

Comment: Sorry, I didn't upload to Stackblitz before, you can look it from my github I guess. ecause it doesn't work on Stackblitz due to not having api.
https://github.com/Olcaytp/ETicaretClient

Comment: oh right I forgot your data is populated by a actual backend instead of being hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

Answer is that i should specify the length of the paginator. I just changed these lines.

```
this.paginator.length = allProducts.totalProductCount;
```